# Littlewood Paley characterization of BMO spaces

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, littlewood-paley-theory

I know that there is a Littlewood-Paley characterization of Hardy spaces (for instance, this is found in Grafakos, Modern Fourier Analysis, section 6.4.6). I'd like to know if a similar characterization holds for BMO spaces, and where I could find that.
Any little help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is a characterisation of Littlewood-Paley theory in terms of $BMO$. By making use of Carleson measures, Littlewood-Paley theory was used to establish the duality between $H^1$ and $BMO$. We can show that $f\in BMO$ if and only if we can write it as a special convolution looking suspiciously similar to the g-function in terms of Carleson measures. Anyway, check out the following: 
 http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02836580
https://mospace.umsystem.edu/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10355/15980/research.pdf?sequence=2
Hope this helps!